# PHP array insertions do not work as expected

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to insert some items (suppose `n` items), which are all different from each other, to an array. Somehow, the final array consists of `n` items, **Which all are the same item: the last inserted item.**

This is my code:

```
$searchResults_data = [];
foreach($allowSearch as $searchResultItem) {
    $searchResultJSon->dealid = $searchResultItem['id'];
    $searchResultJSon->title = $searchResultItem['title'];
    //$from->send(json_encode($searchResultJSon)); --- DEBUGGING1 ---
    //$from->send(json_encode($searchResults_data)); --- DEBUGGING2 ---
    $searchResults_data[] =  $searchResultJSon;
}
```

So I tried to figure out why is that.. using `DEBUGGING1`,`DEBUGGING2` (in the client side, I get the messages sent by `$from->send()` and simply `alert()` them).

When alerting the `DEBUGGING1` messages - I do see that all the items are correct and different from each other.

When alerting the `DEBUGGING2` messages - the array duplicates the last inserted item each loop. So assume I insert `n` items, The array in the `i-th` loop will be: `[item-i, item-i, item-i, ... item-i]` **instead of** `[item-1, item-2, item-3,...,item-i]`

Comment: Where is `$searchResultJSon` originally defined?

Comment: @Nick nowhere. Only in the foreach loop without pre-declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not creating a new object each time you go through the loop, so when you push `$searchResultJSon` into `$searchResults_data` you are pushing the same object, and the changes you make to it in the last iteration of the loop are reflected in *all* the values in `$searchResults_data`. You can work around that by creating a new object in each pass:

```
$searchResults_data = [];
foreach($allowSearch as $searchResultItem) {
    $searchResultJSon = new StdClass();
    $searchResultJSon->dealid = $searchResultItem['id'];
    $searchResultJSon->title = $searchResultItem['title'];
    //$from->send(json_encode($searchResultJSon)); --- DEBUGGING1 ---
    //$from->send(json_encode($searchResults_data)); --- DEBUGGING2 ---
    $searchResults_data[] =  $searchResultJSon;
}
```

Comment: Why a new object is required? Why updating its fields  not working?

Comment: @QwertTrewq because when you push an object into an array, you only push a reference to the object, not a copy of it. So your array fills with references to the same object, and when you change *any* copy of the object you change all the references as well. By creating a new object each time through the loop you avoid that problem.

Comment: @QwertTrewq I made a small demo here https://3v4l.org/eX4Zl note in the first block that even without pushing the object into the array, just changing its values affect the values of the references in the array.